# Cant return $couponDetails->couponName; value in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-controller, laravel-models

```php
$couponCode = $request->couponCode;

// Get coupon details by coupon code
$coupon = Coupon::where('couponCode', $couponCode)
    ->get()
    ->first();

$couponDetails = response()->json($coupon);

return $couponDetails->couponName;
```

That returns as:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::$couponName (500 Internal Server Error)

I am tring to get couponName value from couponDetails

Comment: Start by looking at what $coupon is `dd($coupon);` and showing us. You have to start your debugging before coming here

Comment: Also if you are getting an error, please show us that error as a seperate line in your question and EXACTLY as it was give to you, no summarising

Comment: I think `$coupon->couponName` should return the object.

Comment: `$couponDetails` is a `JsonResponse`, not the coupon, so it won't be what you think it is. Remove `$couponDetails = response()->json($coupon);` and return `$coupon->couponName`. Also, `->get()->first()` is unnecessary, because that's returning a collection of probably a single item, then grabbing the first time. Just use `->first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because property you're trying to access doesn't exist for the class `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse`.

You have two ways to avoid this:

1. Either return:

   ```php
   return $coupon->couponName;
   ```
2. Get the data from JsonResponse class:

   ```php
   return $couponDetails->getData()->couponName;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As another user already stated but not with more code, I will show you how to do it:

```php
// Store coupon code on variable (no need to)
$couponCode = $request->couponCode;

// Get coupon details by coupon code (directly use first() so you get the model in one run)
$coupon = Coupon::where('couponCode', $couponCode)->first();

// Here you can either return the model as a JSON response (and in the view you do `$data->couponName`
response()->json(['data' => $coupon]);

// Or you directly return the coupon name
return $couponDetails->couponName;
```